# FireMonkey (FMX) code not compiling for Linux, works well on Win64

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to extract pixel color values from a bitmap into a 2-dimensional array of floating point values for later post processing.

This code works fine for me on Win64, but I can't compile this code now for Linux using the FMX framework.

```
type
  TMyFunction = array of array of Real;    

var
  X, Y: Integer;
  CurrentData : TBitmapData;
  Color: TAlphaColor;
  afct :  TMyFunction;
  abmp : TBitmap; 

if (abmp.Map(TMapAccess.Read, CurrentData)) then
begin
  try
    for X := 0 to abmp.Width - 1 do
      for Y := 0 to abmp.Height - 1 do
      begin
        Color := CurrentData.GetPixel(X, Y);
        afct[X, Y] := TColorRec.ColorToRGB(Color).ToSingle;
      end;
  finally
    abmp.Unmap(CurrentData);
  end;
end;
```

The error message goes like this:

> [DCC Error] numeric.pas(444): E2018 Record, object or class type required

I can't change the `TMyFunction` as used in many places in my project.

Why does the assignment / `.ToSingle` require something different between Windows and Linux?

Comment: Why do you have 2D array of `Real` but assign a `Single` value to each array element? Do you know that in current implementation `Real` is equivalent to `Double`?

Comment: I guess/hope that some part of your code, not visible here, does SetLength() on the dynamic array and all its subarrays? Although, if not, that would be a runtime problem, and not a compile-time problem.

Comment: we are executing math functions  like FFT  on these data, that's why we need  a floating point datatype  somewhere as F(x,y); Any yes - Setlength is  not shown here,  I only want to  know why  .ToSingle  does not  work under LINUX/compiling this  code  for LINUX